# Errors while controlling PWM with sysfs

Tags: buildroot, led, pwm, armv8, sysfs

I build a custom image with buildroot. Now I try to control a LED with PWM through sysfs. This worked with DietPi OS. [Here](https://forum.radxa.com/t/how-to-use-any-pwm-on-radxa-zero-sysfs/15745/3) I describe exactly how I've done it.

Unfortunately, this don't work in my custom Image. I see kernel messages and nothing happens with the LED.

```
[ 3248.294890] meson-pwm ff807000.pwm: .apply is supposed to round down duty_cycle (requested: 100/10000, applied: 9758/9840)
[ 3248.298727] meson-pwm ff807000.pwm: .apply is not idempotent (ena=1 pol=292568176 82/9840) -> (ena=1 pol=0 41/9676)
[ 3248.303312] meson-pwm ff807000.pwm: .apply didn't pick the best available period (requested: 10000, applied: 0, possible: 9676)
[ 3248.310794] meson-pwm ff807000.pwm: .apply is not idempotent (ena=1 pol=292568176 0/0) -> (ena=1 pol=0 0/0)
[ 3309.485314] meson-pwm ff807000.pwm: .apply is supposed to round down duty_cycle (requested: 900/10000, applied: 8979/9840)
[ 3309.489213] meson-pwm ff807000.pwm: .apply is not idempotent (ena=1 pol=292568176 861/9840) -> (ena=1 pol=0 820/9676)
[ 3312.601374] meson-pwm ff807000.pwm: .apply is not idempotent (ena=1 pol=292568176 0/0) -> (ena=1 pol=0 0/0)
```

I don't even understand the message. Can someone at least explain this log?

I also see this during boot. Is this maybe somehow related?

```
[    0.081403] reg-fixed-voltage regulator-flash_1v8: Failed to register regulator: -517
[    0.081747] reg-fixed-voltage regulator-vcc_1v8: Failed to register regulator: -517
[    0.081838] reg-fixed-voltage regulator-vcc_3v3: Failed to register regulator: -517
[    0.081976] reg-fixed-voltage regulator-vddao_1v8: Failed to register regulator: -517
```

- [Radxa Zero v1.51 Datasheet](https://dl.radxa.com/zero/docs/hw/S905Y2%20Quick%20Reference%20Manual%20v0.7.pdf) ARMv8, builroot-2022.11
- [Pinout](https://wiki.radxa.com/Zero/hardware/gpio)
- [Original Post](https://forum.radxa.com/t/radxa-zero-voltage-regulators-with-buildroot-causing-pwm-problems/16285)
- [Full logs](https://pastebin.com/XuDgUiTp)